# Extjs- Grid column headers refresh for every search

Tags: sorting, extjs, default, datagridcolumnheader

I am trying to sort my results grid based on a default column header every time the results gets displayed. I tried giving a sorter to the store and it worked fine when the page loads first time. Its working as I want it to be. But the problem arises only when I try to click on a different column header in the grid. When I click on a different header it sorts based on that particular column values. If I click on search button at this point of time without reloading the page, the search results get displayed and are sorted based on my previous selected column. I want this to be sorted based on the default column. Problem is the grid gets refreshed with search results every time I click on search or reset buttons but the column headers are not getting refreshed. So the results are getting sorted based on my previous selection. To fix this problem, I am trying to reload the whole page every time I click on search or reset. Is there a way that I can refresh the column headers along with the search results every time I click on the search so that the results get sorted based on the default column header. I am able to refresh the search results and the pagination part for every search but not the column headers. Any solution...

Thanks....

Answer (score 2):

One thing you didn't mention is whether you really want to allow the user to sort by different columns.

You can switch this behaviour off in the columns definition using `sortable: false`
http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.grid.column.Column-cfg-sortable

If you want to keep that behaviour, you can replace the sorters with the default one again on every load:

```
var myDefaultSorter=Ext.create('Ext.util.Sorter',{
    property:"MyProperty",
    direction:"ASC"
});

store.on('beforeload',function(store) {
    store.sorters.clear();
    store.sorters.add(myDefaultSorter);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried store.sorters.clear() ?